# Convert Type Output to String

Tags: autolisp

is it possible to collect the output of the `type` function and return it as a string? I can write out a list of conditions for each type of output this function can produce, but I'm hoping I can just convert the output directly into a string variable.

```lisp
(type "Test")
STR ;<--- System value type

(cond ((= 'STR (type "Test")) "STR"))
"STR" ;<- String value type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research, I found these two functions: `vl-princ-to-string` and `vl-prin1-to-string`.

```lisp
(vl-princ-to-string (type "Test"))
"STR"

(vl-prin1-to-string (type "Test"))
"STR"
```

Answer (score 1):

`vl-princ-to-string` or `vl-prin1-to-string` will generate a string representation of *any* type of AutoLISP data (though, be aware that you have no control over the resulting precision of numerical data, as these functions operate independently of the `LUPREC`/`AUPREC` system variables and do not accept any precision arguments).

Since the `type` function returns a symbol, you can use the `vl-symbol-name` function to convert the symbol to a string, e.g.:

```lisp
_$ (vl-symbol-name (type "test"))
"STR"
```

Note also that, contrary to your answer, the `vl-*` functions do not require the prior evaluation of `(vl-load-com)`, this is only required for ActiveX functions (`vla-*`/`vlax-*`).

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, the application I'm using (DraftSight) doesn't have this function in its [library](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/English/api/draftsightlispreference/vlisp/HelpViewerDS.aspx?version=2022&prod=api&lang=English&path=draftsightlispreference%2fvlisp%2fvl_vl_functions.htm).